# Google Chat randomly hyperlinks words like "see", "zoo", "walmart", and "in a" on Samsung Galaxy S22, Android 13

Tags: samsung, hyperlinks, android-13, google-chat

I am using Google Chat from GMail on Samsung Galaxy S22, Android 13. Some words like "see", "zoo", "walmart", and "in a" are linked randomly. When I tap it, I can search for the word(s) or click map which actually doesn't do anything as it's not a place.

I don't see any recently added apps that might be doing this. I have also restarted the phone as well as wiped the cache and data for GMail to attempt to fix it. The only thing I can think of is the update I performed yesterday as I don't remember seeing this happen prior to that.

How to fix it?

Comment: Since you tagged this question with [tag:google-hangouts], did you mean that the issue is only on Google Hangouts? Does it do anything when tapped? If it's possible and not sensitive, could you post a screenshot of it? Also, in case it's related, could you also mention the device model?

Comment: It is actually only happening in Google Chat. Which isn't an option. I am not sure if that is different than Google Hangouts or not. When I tap it I can search for the word(s) or click map which actually doesn't do anything as its not a place.

Comment: It is a Samsung S22 which I have started finding this is a common Samsung issue apparently.

Answer (score 0):

It's been happening on my Note20 as well.  I think I found the setting that controls it, but it's kind of crap for a fix because it disables a lot of other things as well.  To get to the setting, open the Gmail app and go into settings.  Choose the account-specific settings for the account you are using with Chat.  Scroll down about one screen worth and you will see a checkbox option that says:

> **Smart features and personalization**
>
> Gmail, Chat, and Meet may use my email, chat, and video content to personalize my experience and provide smart features. If I opt out, such features will be turned off.

Turning this off will not un-create the random word links it made in the past, but it will stop all future links from appearing.  However, doing so will also disable the smart features in other Google products on your phone, as well as disabling features like Package Tracking, Smart Compose, and Smart Reply.  So unfortunately, it seems that either you live with the janky, buggy link generation that Chat wants to do, or you have to live without some of the other more useful features you'd find in Chat, Gmail, and other Google apps.